# What is difference between AndroidJavaObject and AndroidJavaClass in Unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, scripting, native

I made a plugin for my android game And for calling this plugin in my unity scripts I do not know to use `AndroidJavaObject` or `AndroidJavaClass`.

Because in some of the tutorials that I saw, they doing something like this :

```
AndroidJavaObject test = new AndroidJavaObject("com.aaa.bbb.ccc");
test.Call<string>("tester");
```

and in otherone tutorials :

```
AndroidJavaClass test = new AndroidJavaClass("com.aaa.bbb.ccc");
myClass.Call("testMethod", new object[] { "testString" } );
```

and in some others they do :

```
AndroidJavaClass test = new AndroidJavaClass("com.aaa.bbb.ccc");
AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = test.GetStatic("currentActivity");
```

I just want to know what is difference between this ways ?
And Which one is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AndroidJavaObject` is for creating instances of that class and calling instance methods on it.

`AndroidJavaClass` is for calling static class methods or accessing static fields.

Depending on the java API you have to you use either `AndroidJavaObject` or `AndroidJavaClass`.